Why is Webex crashing at application startup in AlmaLinux?
I have a fresh install of AlmaLinux and I need Webex for org chat rooms.
I've installed Webex through the Webex.rpm file provided on their official website.
After successfully installing, I tried to sign in with my Webex email and password. After entering my password and clicking "Connect", the Webex window briefly opens and shows a "loading" spinner, and then immediately closes.
Every time I try to relaunch, the same issue happens.
I have tried uninstalling & reinstalling the program to no avail.
I have found a log file that gets updated with every launch: ~/home/.share/Webex/logArchive/last_run_current_log.txt, but I don't see an error on the last line that tells me what caused the sudden process termination.
If I run ps -ax | grep cisco I see a single Cisco process but the PID keeps changing, so it's almost like it's in a non-terminating loop of trying to boot, failing, trying to boot, failing, etc.
What the heck is going on? Does anyone have any ideas for ways to figure out what's causing this, or - even better - has anyone gone through this issue and successfully resolved it?

It turns out it was just blocked by selinux. After fixing that configuration I was good to go.

If you have a fresh install of AlmaLinux (the community version of RHEL) I imagine it's version 9.
Webex for Linux is only available for

Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04

RHEL 8.2 and 8.3


(Source.)
You could try downgrading the version of the Mesa drivers installed on your machine, some people solved the problem this way.

Thanks for the reply. It turned out to be an selinux configuration set up by IT.
